different behavior of two seemingly identical code
I am writing a code to check parentheses of a expression, which is stored as a string.
Each character of the string is stored in tokens[i].type.
To be more detailed, this function is designed for lexical analysis, breaking down expressions. We know that a expr wrapped by parentheses is still a expr, <expr> ::= "(" <expr> ")"  So, if check_parentheses() returns true, we can step inside and cope with the expr itself.
Function should return true for (1+2), 
and return false for (1+2)*(3+4)
The code:
bool check_parentheses(int p, int q)
{
  int cnt = 0;
  int i = p;
  for(; i <= q; ++i)
  {
    if(tokens[i].type == '(') { ++cnt; }
    else if(tokens[i].type == ')') { --cnt; }
    if(cnt == 0 && tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')') {break;}
  }
  if(i == q) return true; else return false;
  return false;
 
  // int i = p;
  // for(; i <= q; ++i)
  // {
  //   if(tokens[i].type == '(') {++cnt;}
  //   else if(tokens[i].type == ')') {--cnt;}
  //   if(cnt == 0 && tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')' && i == q)
  //     return true;
  //   else
  //     return false;
  // }
  // return false;
}

The "live" code runs well while the "dormant" version works badly. Using gdb I found that every time it runs at the for() loop, the "dormant" version just skips the loop and returns false, while the other steps into the loop and executes the code normally.
I suppose the two are identical and wonder why they behave differently.

The commented code will never iterate more than the entering single iteration. You have an if-else that will always return in either case, which breaks the loop and exists the function. The uncommented code doesn't do that.

SO posting tip: The way you've shown two blocks of code is perfectly fine. Cloud storage is not your worry. It would have been better to post two completely separate versions of the entire function. Label one "Ver1.c" and the other "Ver2.c". Then everyone can refer to either version without "terminology" problems. ("Annotated" was a very good try. In programmer's jargon, "commented out" is the term/phrase used. "Annotated" is a synonym for "commented", but not for "commented out"... Ask Google: "difference commented commented-out". Keep on truckin' :-)

Having reformatted the OP's posting, the presence of an if/else in the "commented out" version becomes visible. The function will return a value before looping to check the second element of the array. (Credit to @WhozCraig who reported this in a comment 3 minutes after the question was posted.)
The function returns false from inside the loop because the first parentheses has already resulted in cnt being incremented before the if( cnt == 0 ...

Consider the OP's "working" code inside the for() loop:

if(cnt == 0 && tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')') {break;}

If the initial character IS NOT '(', then the 2nd term of the conditional is always false and the break; is never followed.
If the initial character IS '(', then cnt increments and decrements as tokens are examined.
Evaluating (1+2)*(3+4) satisfies the if() prematurely, triggering break;. The external if() checks that the full set of tokens has been examined and returns false.
Testing with (1+2) returns true (as seems to be intended).
Unfortunately, testing with (1+2, 1+2) or 1(*)2 would also return true. The appearance of testing enclosing parentheses is misleading and confusing (and possibly incorrect, in this limited context.)

Based on OP's original text

If the exp is (1+2) return true, if is (1+2)*(3+4) return false

the function can be vastly simplified:
bool check_parentheses( int p, int q ) {
    bool ok = ( tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')' ); // test both ends

    for( p += 1; ok && p < q; p++ )
        ok = tokens[p].type != '(' && tokens[p].type != ')'; // test "meat in the middle"

    return p == q && ok; // reached end, and all is okay (or not)
}


OP: "I suppose the two are identical and wonder why they behave differently."
There's a big difference between break; and return;. You have to think your way through each of the execution paths to follow what the code will do under various circumstances.
In the "commented out" version, the premature false returned comes from inside the loop; not from the function's final return false; statement.

Thanks for your explanation, I will try to make my post comprehensive the next time

@Lingardx No sweat; and thank you, too. The more you help us, the better we can help you... Good luck going forward :-)

@Lingardx: the requirement that the function return false for (1+2)*(3+4) is surprising, but what about ((1+2)*3) ? Should it return true or false?  The code in this answer returns false, which is incorrect IMHO.

@Fe2O3: the return statement can be simplified as return ok;

@chqrlie "requirement surprising"?? Shouldn't be. It's stated in the OP's post. Should you think the OP's post is "unclear" or "lacking in details", SO has "comments" and/or VTC options you could use... If you have questions about the OP's question, it would be better to post them below the OP's question where it is more likely they'll be seen... Do, however, be careful that you do not cause the OP to alter the "sense" of the question thereby invalidating existing answers already posted. The time to seek clarity is while the ink on the OP's post is still wet; not after you've answered it.

@Fe2O3: Im afraid your code does not attempt to balance the parentheses, which the OP did, albeit in a convoluted way. The case of ((1+2)*3) is not specified as a requirement, but seems implied from the working code.  Since this is the accepted answer, I asked the OP for clarification.

@chqrlie Please take this with the friendly and respectful intentions I have typing it: The time to seek clarity is before answering... Check out the timestamps on these Q&A interactions. Notice an answer after 6min, then a criticism at 8 min, and OP responds to 7 UV'd answer at 20 min showing OP has found own solution (that is NOT the answer that's UV'd)... I'm leaving soon... This place has problems that long-term "community members" aren't interested in solving... Just loitering for a few days. (Loved your monthOrd hash! :-)...

@chqrlie Re: "does not attempt to balance" You're right! The comment response to some SO Q's is: "Don't describe your problem; show us your code." To others it's: "Okay, code's there. What's the input and both current and expected output?" In this case, I went for the "most informative" aspect, the OP's good & bad input examples... It's no big thing... OP is very welcome to post another question if your observations expand his/her appreciation of possibilities of input... Cheers! :-)

The alternatives are not equivalent:

The first version, if(cnt == 0 && tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')') {break;} will break if the first token is an open parenthesis, the last a close parenthesis and a there is a matching ) in the string. So it will break before the end for (1+2) and (1+2)*(3+4) yet i == q will be true for the first and false for the second. Unmatched ( will cause the loop to run to the end, leaving  with i equal to q+1, hence returning false too.

In the second version, if(cnt == 0 && tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')' && i == q) only returns true at the end of the string if you reach a cnt of zero and both the first and last tokens form a pair of parentheses. In all other cases, the function returns false immediately, which is a problem, because the loop never reaches the end of the string, it returns false on the first test even if p == q.


You want the expression have balanced parentheses inside the pair of surrounding parentheses.
Here is a simpler alternative:
bool check_parentheses(int p, int q)
{
    if (tokens[p].type != '(' || tokens[q].type != ')')
        return false;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = p + 1; i < q; i++) {
        if (tokens[i].type == '(') {
            ++count;
        } else
        if (tokens[i].type == ')') {
            --count;
            if (count < 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return count == 0;
}


hi, I have double check your code and find something might be wrong. Consider the input string of 1+(3), the output should be false but I suppose your code will return true instead.

Yes, the code will return true as the parentheses are correctly balanced.  Why do you think check_parentheses should return false in this case?

I doubt there might be some misunderstading. I have modified the discription to make it clear.

@Lingardx So you simply want to check that the expression has an opening parenthesis as first token, and a closing parenthesis as last token? You should make that clear in your question. Probably some more examples and the expected result will help to understand.

@thebusybee After "improving" the OP's question (formatting and some terminology), from the outset the OP has provided "expected results". True is begin & end are a pair of parentheses, AND there are no parentheses between the two ends of the array examined. It's not rocket science...

@Fe2O3: you are correct, reading code is so much more difficult than writing it... Answer amended.
